# fabric - "Command(s) not found" error when passing arguments within Eclipse (PyDev)?

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line-arguments, pydev, fabric

I've been playing with [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html).

With a hello world program:

```
def hello(name="world"):
    print("hello %s!" % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from fabric.main import main
    sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__,] + sys.argv[1:]
    main()
```

I can pass the argument `hello:name=quanta` and get the "hello quanta! result.

But with a below script:

```
from fabric.api import run

def hostname(host="localhost"):
    run("hostname")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from fabric.main import main
    sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__,] + sys.argv[1:]
    main()
```

I got the errors:

> Fatal error: Command(s) not found:
>       hostname
>
> Aborting.

when passing `hostname:host=192.168.3.118` as a argument within PyDev.

It's working fine from the command line:

```
$ fab -f hostname.py hostname:host=192.168.3.118
[192.168.3.118] Executing task 'hostname'
[192.168.3.118] run: hostname
[192.168.3.118] out: SVR040-3118.localdomain
[192.168.3.118] out: 

Done.
Disconnecting from 192.168.3.118... done.
```

It's also happen with the `env` dictionary, something like this:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.hosts = ['192.168.3.118', '192.168.6.142']

def hostname():
    run("hostname")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from fabric.main import main
    sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__,] + sys.argv[1:]
    main()
```

although running it from the command line gets the expected results:

```
$ fab -f hostname.py hostname
[192.168.3.118] Executing task 'hostname'
[192.168.3.118] run: hostname
[192.168.3.118] out: SVR040-3118.localdomain
[192.168.3.118] out: 
[192.168.6.142] Executing task 'hostname'
[192.168.6.142] run: hostname
[192.168.6.142] out: SVR040-6142
[192.168.6.142] out: 

Done.
Disconnecting from 192.168.6.142... done.
Disconnecting from 192.168.3.118... done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my silly error.

I'm a Eclipse newcomer.

My source code structure is something like this:

```
src/
├── hello.py
├── hello.pyc
├── hostname.py
├── hostname.pyc
```

Every Python files have own Run configuration. When I open the `hostname.py` file and click on the play button (NOT the down arrow), it is actually running with the `hello` configuration, this is reason for the above errors.

To create a new Python run: 
right click on the file -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> right click on Python Run -> new -> naming it, chose the right Project and Main Module -> switch to Arguments tab -> Set the ${string_prompt} for Program Arguments if you want -> Apply and Run.

For the later run, you can simply chose the right configuration from the down arrow (beside the play button).

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be checking if sys.path is the same when running from one version to another (i.e.: import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path))) and see if it's the same from the command line to Eclipse/PyDev -- if it's not, you probably have some issue in your project configuration inside PyDev -- i.e.: maybe a source folder is not properly set?)

If that's not it, check if the environment variables match (i.e.: if something is working from the command line and not from Eclipse, 99% of the times is because some configuration is different from the command line to Eclipse).